# Android.Orientation Wrong data from sensors,

Tags: android, rotation, sensors, device-orientation

Excuse me . I need your help . I want to get Orientation (s/n/e/w) for augumentet reality , but it show me wrong results(wrong data from sensor) . I use landscape orientation. it is my code(in loadnewsensordata i load data from magnetic field sensor and accelerometer sensor) -

```
    private float[] calculateOrientation() {

        float[] values = new float[3];
        float[] I = new float[16];
        values[0] = 0;
        values[1] = 0;
        values[2] = 0;
        float[] R = new float[16];
        float[] outR = new float[16];
        for (int i = 0; i < R.length; i++) {
            R[i] = 0;
            outR[i] = 0;
        }

        Display display = parrent.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int deviceRot = display.getRotation();


        SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, null, accelData, magnetData);
        switch (deviceRot) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(R,
                        SensorManager.AXIS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_Z,
                        outR);
                break;
//                 rotated left (landscape - keys to bottom)
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(R,
                        SensorManager.AXIS_Y, SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X,
                        outR);
                break;
            // upside down
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(R,
                        SensorManager.AXIS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_Z,
                        outR);
                break;
            // rotated right
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(R,
                        SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Z, SensorManager.AXIS_X,
                        outR);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        SensorManager.getOrientation(outR, values);

        // Convert from Radians to Degrees.
        values[0] = (float) Math.toDegrees(values[0]);
        values[1] = (float) Math.toDegrees(values[1]);
        values[2] = (float) Math.toDegrees(values[2]);
        if (values[0] < 0) {
            values[0] = 360 + values[0];
        }
        return values;
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        loadNewSensorData(event);
        tw1 = (int) calculateOrientation()[0] + " ";
        parrent.viewBearingOnDisplay(tw1);
    }


private void loadNewSensorData(SensorEvent event) {
    final int type = event.sensor.getType(); //Определяем тип датчика

    if (type == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) { //Если акселерометр
        accelData = event.values.clone();
    }

    if (type == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) { //Если геомагнитный датчик
        magnetData = event.values.clone();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to have a switch statement

```
SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, null, accelData, magnetData);
SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(R, SensorManager.AXIS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_Z, outR);
SensorManager.getOrientation(outR, values);
```

The above codes will give you `values[0]` as the direction where the back camera pointed independent of your device orientation.

Comment: What i must do , to get right direction ,when smartphone is in horizontal position (button pointed right and display pointed to user)?

Comment: Nothing? the direction of the back camera does not depend on the orientation of the device (landscape or portrait). Just use the code above independent of the orientation. Of course if the device is laying flat, the camera is pointed to the ground or to the sky then this won't work.

Comment: What do you mean by wrong data? Calibrate your phone (do a few figure 8)

Comment: it show me one value (approximately) ,at all directions.(i can't load photo or screensave ,i not have enough reputation for loading image)

Comment: Post your loadNewSensorData method. Also try your app on another device.

Comment: i rotate my smartphone around and it show me wrong value , then i put smartphone on the table, then i focus camera on north it show me right value.

Comment: You should use TYPE_GRAVITY instead of TYPE_ACCELEROMETER and also you should keep a history and then take the average.

Comment: I use TYPE_GRAVITY but it dont work . My device dont have this sensor.

Comment: Then you have low pass filter the accelerometer values

Comment: thank you for answers ,it was very useful . It was need to calibrate sensor. But method getorientation still  not  work right. I use TYPE_ORIENTATION & filter of values depends on accuracy .

Comment: You should not use TYPE_ORIENTATION since different phones will behave differently.